# Most/Second most + after

Tags: superlatives, logic

> 1. Russia is the most powerful country after the US.

Or

> 2. Russia is the second most powerful country after the US.

Question: Which one of the above should I use to convey that Russia is second to US in terms of overall power.

Personally, I was inclined to believe that number one is the correct version, because to me it is more logically sound to think of 'after' as 'excluding' or 'following'. However I found more instances of number 2 being used on online forums.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What about China? Is it third most powerful after US or second most powerful after Russia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, though I would favour the latter.

The first one requires a little more thought by the listener because, when parsing the sentence on-the-fly, the **after the US** clause changes Russia's position from first to second.

For the second sentence, the first part stands on its own:

> Russia is the second most powerful country

and the **after the US** clause simply provides additional information (who is #1): it's an afterthought, and you could insert a comma to separate it from the main sentence.